# Painting cube with 3 different colours

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Painting cube with 3 colours (using each colour at least one time)
Find no.  of ways to colour the cube.
(Rotation don't change the colouring.)
Solve it for class 9 student in a easier way.
Please

Comment: is the number 96 ways?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

There are $3^6 $ ways to assign $3$ colours (red, green, blue) to $6$ faces.
Subtract the $2^6$ ways that do not use red, $2^6$ ways that do not use green, $2^6$ ways that do not use blue. Rhe $3$ monochromatic way were subtracted twice, so have to be added back in. We count a total of 
$$ 3^6-3\cdot 2^6+3=540.$$ 
However, some of these are just rotated versions of another. A rotation of the cibe is either

- a rotation by $90^\circ$ around an axis through two opposing faces. The only 3-colurings invariant under such a rotation are those with these two faces of different colour and the remaining "belt" of  four faces of the third colour. There are $18$ such colourings, but we count them only as $3$.
- a rotation by $180^\circ$ around an axis through two opposing faces. The only 3-colurings invariant under such a rotation that are not also $90^\circ$ symmetric are those with opposing faces equal. There are $6$ such colourings, but we count them only as $1$.
- a rotation by $180^\circ$ around an axis through two opposing edges.  The only 3-colurings invariant under such a rotation have one pair of opposing faces of one colour, and the other colours used on two adjacent faces each. There are $3\cdot 3\cdot 4=36$ such colourings, but we count them only as $3$.
- a rotation by $120^\circ$ around an axis through two opposing vertices. No 3-colouring can be invariant under such a rotation.

The remaining $540-18-6-36=480$ colourings have no symmetry, hence are identified in groups of $24$ (the total number of cube symmetries) and count only as $20$.
Add back the $3+1+3$ symmetric colourings to arrive at a total of
$$ 27.$$

Comment: it is given that rotation do not affect the coloring. i think you have not noticed it.